# .Net Framework Data Provider error for Oracle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle

I am trying to get data from Oracle in my MVC programe. But getting error.My connection string in Web.Config is

**Error:**

Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Line 49:             return View(db.mytable.ToList());

Source File: c:\Work\WebPrograms\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Controllers\mytableController.cs    Line: 49

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

[ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.]

System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +1426271

System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateConnectionFromProviderName(String providerInvariantName) +56

System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection) +217

System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) +79

System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +289

**I already added reference of Oracle.DataAccess and Oracle.DataAccess.dll is also in my bin directory. .NET framework is 4.O.**

Comment: You need to install Oracle provider not the only dll

Comment: Could you please provide me link?

Comment: Sorry. EF? How to get it? I m very new in MVC.

Comment: Use Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP) Managed Driver. Oracle.DataAccess is obsolete

Comment: Use this - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/install10104-087102.html

Comment: I think, its depreciated but can be use.

Comment: And as well refer http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it.

Comment: You can also add ODP.NET assemblies using NuGet

Comment: How? My system have NuGet.Core. Can be done with it? If possible then give me any link.